# How to test the value of an option field in AL (Dynamics) Business Central

Tags: dynamics-al

I'm new to AL (Business Central). I want to be able to test the value of an option field.

```
if myOptionField::Booking then 
begin
  Message('Booking');
end;
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recomend you to try this way.

```
if rec.myOptionField = myOptionField:: Booking then
begin
  Message('Booking');
end;
```